# Averaging over blocks of a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Suppose we have a vector `v = [NaN NaN 1 2 3 4 NaN NaN NaN 4 5 6]` and we would like to find the average of numbers in each contiguous block which is not `NaN`. What is an efficient way of doing this in MATLAB? (Of course, the actual vector is something much larger than this example.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a vectorized solution that does not require the Image Processing Toolbox.

Suppose your input is slightly more complex (I included a edge case):

```
v = [NaN NaN 1 2 3 4 NaN NaN NaN 4 5 6 NaN 3 NaN 3 4]

% Index non NaNs
nonNaN      = ~isnan(v(:));

% Find the beginning of a sequence and the element after the end
subs        = diff([0; nonNaN]);
start       = subs == 1;
ends        = subs == -1;
% Start labeling sequences progressively
subs(start) = 1:nnz(start);
subs(ends)  = -(1:nnz(ends));
% Expand the labeling 
subs        = cumsum(subs);

% Use accumarray
accumarray(subs(nonNaN), v(nonNaN),[],@mean)
```

Comment: I think `accumarray` is the way to go

Comment: Thanks, very clever use of `cumsum`. Also, thanks for `accumarray`. I have been looking for a command like this for a long time.

Comment: that's possibly the most efficient solution. +1

Comment: Here is another answer by [Cedric Wannaz](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/74285-want-to-calculate-the-sum-of-the-numbers-appear-in-an-array-that-is-mix-of-nans-and-numbers) on Matlab centeral with slightly fewer lines of codes (the question was asked by my friend ...)

Answer (score 1):

you can see if this is efficient enough:

```
b=bwlabel(isfinite(v));
m=zeros(1,max(b));
for n=1:max(b)
   id=find(b==n);
   m(n)=mean(v(id));
end
```

Surprisingly for long vectors `v` I found this to be more efficient than the logical indexing option `mean(v(b==n))`...

Comment: @passerby51 You can use `bwlabel` in conjunction with `accumarray` too btw. You'd have to toss the 0 index though.

Comment: @jucestain, yes `accumarray` seems to be the nice way of dealing with this problem.  For tossing the zeros, this should be enough `subs = b(b~=0)`.